# WPF: Hiding ContextMenu when empty

Tags: wpf, mvvm, contextmenu

I have a context menu that gets menu items through databinding (I'm using the MVVM pattern):

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContextMenuItems}" />
```

This works fine. However, in the cases when there are no menu items to show, I don't want the context menu to show up at all. Is there a way to accomplish this? Some kind of XAML trigger maybe?

I've tried catching the Opened event och closing the context menu when there are no children. This works but the context menu still flashes by...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe bind to your menu items collections count property and use a converter to set the context menu's visibility.

```
 <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContextMenuItems}"
              Visibility="{Binding Path=ContextMenuItems.Count,Converter={StaticResource zeroToHiddenConverter}}">
```

---

```csharp
public  class ZeroToHiddenConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) 
    {
        int count = (int) value;

        if (count == 0) 
        {
            return Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good answer! I tried to trigger HasItems and set visibility on false but then I got a flashing contextmenu for a split second when adding menuitems again but if that's not the case here then this is definitely the way to do it.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please mark this as answered if nothing else needs to be added.

Comment: This is not a complete solution.  The main problem is that the converter isn't called when your first context menu has zero items in it.  The initial property value of 'Count' is 0, so the converter isn't called until the count changes.

Comment: Beware! The getter of `ContextMenuItems` will be called 2 times with this approach. So if you have any logic in the getter, this will be computed two times.

Answer (score 28):

You can define an implicit style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This should work for all your context menus at once.

Comment: Works for me. Very similar to Adam's answer (upvoted too), but I like the Trigger better than the BooleanToVisibilityConverter. And clearly better than the accepted answer - I haven't experienced the flashing context menu Meleak mentioned.

Comment: Better than the Converter option. Problem that remains is that property HasItems is also true when Items (MenuItems) are invisible. There's no HasVisibleItems property :-/

Comment: i tried your approach, it seemed to be pretty simple.
but it wont work if you have a dynamic contextmenu where the items inside will be collapsed if not needed. any suggestions on how to solve that?

Answer (score 3):

Below is how you can set an application wide style for hiding empty context menus.

HasItems is a dependency property on the ContextMenu itself, so you can set the context menu's visibility based on that boolean.

Here is how to do it in a resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityOfBool" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityOfBool}}"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution for a TreeView that uses the OnContextMenuOpening callback. It prevents the problem Alex G mentioned. If you collapse the menu with a XAML style then it does not appear when the contextmenu is empty, however it appears afterwards when you left-click on another item.

The code looks for the TreeViewItem which wants to open the ContextMenu, and if it has no items, it sets the Handled property of the event to true.

```cs
protected override void OnContextMenuOpening(ContextMenuEventArgs e) {
     var item = FindTreeViewItem(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);
     var contextMenu = item.ContextMenu;
     if (contextMenu != null && !contextMenu.HasItems) {
         e.Handled = true;
     }
 }

 private TreeViewItem FindTreeViewItem(DependencyObject dependencyObject) {
     if (dependencyObject == null) {
         return null;
     }
     var treeViewItem = dependencyObject as TreeViewItem;
     if (treeViewItem != null) {
         return treeViewItem;
     }
     return FindTreeViewItem(VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a binding on Visibility on Items.Count with a value converter - that should prevent your menu from appearing :)